# How to remove a commit on repository of GitHub from merge of other repository?

Tags: github

I accidentally merge pull a commit to other repository GitHub ( My local file is not change , this is still correct version). How to remove this version on GitHub? I mean that i revert **(update url post ...) 2db249f** .Please help me!! 
[image: GitHub]

[image: My Local File]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git pull
git rebase -i HEAD~2
git reset --soft HEAD^

git push origin master
```